# Date format challenge

Tags: excel, vba

. . . so I cut & pasted the code from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datecreated-property

and it works just FINE.

It gives me the creation date & time of any file.

BUT

I don't know what "format" it is in, because, having used that routine to acquire "FileDateStamp", this doesn't work :-

```
    FileAge = Application.Function.Now() - FileDateStamp
```

I have tried these :-

```
    Dim FileDateStamp 
    Dim FileDateStamp as Date
    Dim FileDateStamp as Text
```

Each format provides the datestamp, but none works in the formula.
And neither does the "Date(Year, Month, Day)" function on FileDateStamp

Comment: `FileAge = Now - FileDateStamp`. Use `Format$` afterwards to format into something readable.

Comment: `TypeName(f.DateCreated)` tells you it's a `Date`

Comment: "this doesn't work" - in what way does it not work?  `Application.Function.Now()` is not a thing (at least in VBA), but just `Now()` works fine, so `Now - FileDateStamp` gives you file age in days.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is not clear if you are saying that it is a date without a time component, or a datetime, which it is.

Comment: The `Date` datatype includes time - there aren't two separate datatypes.  There might not be any fractional component in an  assigned value though.  You can always `Debug.Print 1 * FileDateStamp` to see the underlying numeric value.

Comment: Eg. compare `Debug.Print DateSerial(2021, 9, 3) * 1` and  `Debug.Print Now * 1`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for clarifying that w.r.t. VBA. I guess that Date vs DateTime was a battle lost long ago :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns a value of data type *Date*.

However, you can use VBA to reduce to a minimum:

```vb
Dim FileSpec As String
Dim FileAge  As Double
Dim TextAge  As String

FileSpec = "d:\path\filename.ext"
FileAge = VBA.Now - VBA.FileDateTime(FileSpec)

' Optionally, format as days.hours:minutes:seconds
TextAge = VBA.Fix(FileAge) & "." & VBA.Format(FileAge - VBA.Fix(FileAge), "hh:nn:ss")

Debug.Print FileAge
' for example: 349.739988425928
Debug.Print TextAge
' for example: 349.17:45:35
```

Comment: Thank you !  But I don't have the Functions  "CLng" nor "Format"

Comment: @RobinClay - you might find following one or two tutorials on VBA useful - both `CLng` and `Format` are built-in.

Comment: _I don't have the Functions "CLng" nor "Format"_ ... yes you do. They belong to `VBA`.

Comment: As you seem to require only a _numeric_ age of the file, the solution can be reduced further. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Well . .  I did suspect that I did have those two functions, so I tried typing them in - but they just produced an error.

Comment: OK. Please mark as answered if you feel so.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what you're asking for, but I think this is what you might be looking for.

At the time of writing, the UTC datetime is 2021-09-03 18:54:12. The UTC creation of the file in the code is 2020-06-12 14:04:50 (448 days ago).

Using the [DateDiff function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function):

```
Function GetFileDateTime(filespec)
    Dim fs, f, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    GetFileDateTime = f.DateCreated
End Function

Sub ShowSampleDiff()
    Dim fname As String
    fname = "C:\temp\asp.txt"
    Dim diff As Long
    diff = DateDiff("d", GetFileDateTime(fname), Now())
    MsgBox (diff)
End Sub
```

The code shows a message box with the text "448".

Comment: Thank you !   But I don't have the code for the "DateDif" Function

Comment: @RobinClay In my answer I refer to the "DateDiff" function, not "DateDif" with one "f".

Comment: This will not return the age of the file, only the difference in calendar dates, as the timeparts will be ignored.

Comment: @ 
Andrew Morton
Sticky keyboard, sorry.  Yes, "DateDiff" with two Fs

Comment: @ 
Gustav
 - good enough for MY purpose - but for "completeness" how would you solve that ?

Comment: @RobinClay What do you want from the calculation? For example, you might want the age of the file in days, as shown, or you might want it in hours, or something else. (Oh, and DateDiff is a built-in function - you can click on the link in my answer to see its documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not clear in what you want.

This works to return the number of days (and fractional days)

```
    Dim FileDateStamp As Date    
    FileDateStamp = f.DateCreated
    s = "Created: " & FileDateStamp
    
    MsgBox s & vbLf & Now - FileDateStamp
```

For a particular file, the above returns:

[image]

Depending on what you want for output, you could format the result of:

```
FileAge = Now - FileDateStamp
```

Comment: Thank you - but the "challenge" is to find the age of the file, rather than being given the two dates.  e.g. That could be followed by code along the lines of "If the file is more than a week old, delete it."  i.e.. If FileAge > 7 then delete file

Comment: @RobinClay Huh? Silly me.  I would have thought the age of the file in Days would be sufficient. What is the problem with you converting the days difference into an "age"?

Comment: That WAS exactly my problem !  But "all sorted now".  Thanks for your help.